# Is there any way to share report to user

Tags: sharing, reports-folder

How can we share a single report to user rather than giving access to folder

Comment: Go through this link : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=analytics_share_folder_with_user.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Answer (score 1):

From the following [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=analytics_share_folder_with_user.htm&type=0&language=en_US):

> 1. On the Reports tab, hover over a report folder in the left pane, click Pin, and then select Share.
> 2. Select Internal Users.
> 3. Find the user you want, click <kbd>Share</kbd>, and choose an access level.
>      To search, just start entering a name.
> 4. Click <kbd>Done</kbd>, review your changes, and click Close.